# KeyError in Python 3.4

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I made a dictionary in python and so far there's nothing wrong when I print it like this:

```
print(video_game_company)
```

and I would get the expected result:

```
{('Street Fighter IV', 'Resident Evil 4'): 'Capcom', ('Crash Bandicoot', 'Uncharted', 'The Last of Us'): 'Naughty Dog', ('Prince of Persia: The Forgotten Sands', "Assassin's Creed", 'Watch Dogs'): 'Ubisoft'}
```

The indexes are as follows:

1. Ubisoft
2. Capcom
3. Naughty Dog

but when I type:

```
print("%s" % video_game_company["Capcom"])
```

I get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'Capcom'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`__getitem__` on a dictionary gets keys, `'Capcom'` etc. are values- hence the error.

You should switch around each key and value to get the desired behaviour:

```
{'Ubisoft': ('Prince of Persia: The Forgotten Sands', "Assassin's Creed", 'Watch Dogs'), 'Naughty Dog': ('Crash Bandicoot', 'Uncharted', 'The Last of Us'), 'Capcom': ('Street Fighter IV', 'Resident Evil 4')}
```

---

Now it works properly:

```
print("%s" % video_game_company["Capcom"])
# ('Street Fighter IV', 'Resident Evil 4')
```

Answer (score 1):

"Capcom" is not a key in the dictionary.It's a value for the key ('Street Fighter IV', 'Resident Evil 4').So  video_game_company['Capcom'] results in a keyError(Obviously....since there is no such key 'Capcom').

Answer (score 0):

'Capcom', 'Ubisoft' and 'Naughty Dog' are values and not keys of your dictionary.

```
print("%s" % video_game_company[('Street Fighter IV', 'Resident Evil 4')])  
# display Capcom
```

You need to invert keys and values in your dict to be able to do `video_game_company["Capcom"]`

```
video_game_company = {'Ubisoft': ('Prince of Persia: The Forgotten Sands', "Assassin's Creed", 'Watch Dogs'),
                      'Naughty Dog': ('Crash Bandicoot', 'Uncharted', 'The Last of Us'), 
                      'Capcom': ('Street Fighter IV', 'Resident Evil 4')}

print("%s" % video_game_company["Capcom"])
# displays ('Street Fighter IV', 'Resident Evil 4')
```